# Compute value for different properties of object

Tags: javascript

Given an array of objects

```
function Example(x, y){
  this.prop1 = x;
  this.prop2 = y;
}
var exampleArray = new Array();
exampleArray.push(nex Example(0,1));
exampleArray.push(nex Example(1,3));
```

Now I would like to add a function which computes the average for one of the properties

```
function calcAvg(exampleArray, 'prop1') -> 0.5
function calcAvg(exampleArray, 'prop2') -> 2
```

If I don't want to use jQuery or other libraries, is there a generic way to do this?

Comment: @Teemu I want to calc the average of prop1 over all elements in the array, but specify which property of the stored object should be averaged over. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `Array.prototype.reduce` method and check for valid property:

```
function Example(x, y) {
    this.prop1 = x;
    this.prop2 = y;
}
var exampleArray = new Array();
exampleArray.push(new Example(0, 1));
exampleArray.push(new Example(1, 3));

function calcAvg(arr, prop) {
    if (typeof arr[0] === 'object' && !arr[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        throw new Error(prop + " doesn't exist in objects within specified array!");
    }

    var avg = arr.reduce(function(prevObj, nextObj){
        return prevObj[prop] + nextObj[prop]; 
    });

    return avg/arr.length;
}

console.log(calcAvg(exampleArray, 'prop2')); // output: 2
```

Comment: I tried using the technique, but for some reason the arr.reduce always returns an actual object from the array. What should happen in the case of a one-element array?

Comment: if an array contains only one element, then taking `average`  doesn't make sense. To get the property value of a single object in array you may just use `exampleArray[0]['prop2']`

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work ,
You need to iterate through all `Example` objects in the array and add the given property's value in a variable e.g. `sum` and then at the end divide it by total number of objects in the array to get average.

```
console.log(avg(exampleArray, 'prop1'));

function avg (array, propName){
     var sum = 0;
     array.forEach(function(exm){ 
        sum+= exm[propName];  
    });
    return sum / array.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code iterates over every value of `arr`, searches for property `prop` in every value, pushes the value of that property to an array named `values` and returns the sum of all the values in `values` divided by the number of values in it.

```
function calcAvg(arr,prop){
  var values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    values.push(arr[i][prop]);
  }
  var sum = values.reduce(function(prev,current){
     return prev+current;
  });
  return sum/values.length;
}
```

Demo [is here.](http://jsbin.com/huqoco/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for it.

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
function Example(x, y) {
    this.prop1 = x;
    this.prop2 = y;
}

function calcAvg(array, key) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + a[key];
    }, 0) / array.length;
}

var exampleArray = [new Example(0, 1), new Example(1, 3)],
    avgProp1 = calcAvg(exampleArray, 'prop1'),
    avgProp2 = calcAvg(exampleArray, 'prop2');

document.write(avgProp1 + '<br>');
document.write(avgProp2);
```